# String Property is null

Tags: c#, string

I'm a beginner in C# and today I came across this interesting thing. When I tried to compare an empty string property by `string.Empty`.

Why does this code return false, when it is literally empty?

```
private string _id;

public string Id 
{
   get => _id;
   set
   {
   if (value != string.Empty)
      _id = value;
   }
}

// ... code ...

// this condition returns false
if(Id == string.Empty)
{
   // any code is here
}
```

Just replaced `string.Empty` with `null` and it works as expected.
I guess that string wasn't initialized and equaled `null`, not "".

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question in the last sentence.

Comment: Did you ever assign to `Id`, it defaults to `null`

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama so I was right about the initialization, thank you!

Comment: `null` is not `String.Empty`. Also, if you're using `null` then you should use `private string? id` instead of `private string _id`.

Comment: `string` is a reference type, same as your own classes. Its default value is `null`, not the empty string.

Comment: Got it, I need to learn more about types. thank you a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two kinds of types in C#: reference types and value types. Variables of reference types store references to their data (objects), while variables of value types directly contain their data. `String` is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

So if you create a variable for reference type and don't initialize it there is no value in it and there is no object and no reference to this non-existent object. Just `null`.

If you compare "non-existence" with some real string object it will returns false because nothing not equals to something.

Also, if you want to check both null and empty strings in your condition, you can use [`string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorempty).

> `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` Indicates whether the specified string is null or an empty string ("").

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Id))
{
    // your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, the code is incomplete but the property may not have been initialized.

The uninitialized value for a `string` is `null` (as for every other classes).
Note that a struct behaves differently.